# is it possible that, if markers radiuses crosses each other not to draw marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this is my code google maps markers with circle, so I want on click not to draw markers if theres circles crossing each other

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     var marker3 = placeMarker(event.latLng);
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function(event) {
       });
  });
  function placeMarker(location) {
      var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map,
          draggable:true,   
      });
      radius = new google.maps.Circle(circleRadius);
      radius.bindTo('center', marker3, 'position');
      return marker3;
  }
```

Comment: loop through the existing markers, measure the distance (using the geometry library) from where you are about to put a marker to each marker's location. If that distance is greater than `circleRadius`, place the marker. If not, do nothing.

Comment: More context would be helpful!

Comment: Unclear. What is `circleRadius`? Where does it come from? Is it always the same radius for each marker? "if circles cross each others", do you need to compare 2 markers or 1 markers towards many? Depending on your answers to these, you would get different answers. Dr.Molle's answer seems like a good solution if there are many markers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible approach:
Create 2 circles for each marker, the existing and another, transparent circle with double radius of the first marker.

The 2nd circle will not be visible on the map, but will still be there and prevent the map from triggering the click-event.

```
  radius = new google.maps.Circle(circleRadius);
  radius2 = new  google.maps.Circle({fillOpacity:.0001,
                                     strokeWeight:0,
                                     map:radius.getMap(),
                                     radius:radius.getRadius()*2});
  radius.bindTo('center', marker3, 'position');
  radius2.bindTo('center', marker3, 'position');
```